# LINQ - joining two tables and getting the values from the right part of the join if it exists throw exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table of questions and a table of answers

I always need to display the list of questions regardless and there is a corresponsing asnwer, I need to grab that answer (response)

I use the following code

```
var Questions = db.Questions.Where(x => x.isActive);
var Answers = db.Answers.Where(x => x.AssessmentID == 99);

AssessmentResponseVM model = new AssessmentResponseVM();
foreach (var question in Questions)
{
    AnswerAndQuestions q = new AnswerAndQuestions { };
    q.QuestionText = question.QuestionText;
    q.QuestionID = question.ID;
    q.Response = Answers.Where(a => a.QuestionID == question.ID).SingleOrDefault().Response; <--- throws exception if there is no answer for the question
    model.Questions.Add(q);
}
```

But get this error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

On this line

```
q.Response = Answers.Where(a => a.QuestionID == question.ID).SingleOrDefault().Response;
```

Comment: You cannot get the value of a property of an object that is `null`  - test for `null` first, and if not, then access the `Response` property

Comment: `var answer = Answers.Where(a => a.QuestionID == question.ID).SingleOrDefault(); if (answer != null) { q.Response = answer.Response; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that is the way I decided to do it

Answer (score 0):

change

```
q.Response = Answers.Where(a => a.QuestionID == question.ID).SingleOrDefault().Response;
```

to this code

```
q.Response=Answers.Any(a=>a.QuestionID==question.ID)?Answers.firstOrDefault(a => a.QuestionID == question.ID).Response:new Response();
```

Comment: 'IQueryable<Answer>' does not contain a definition for 'firstOrDefault' and no extension method 'firstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<Answer>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @totalitarian; then try with singleorDefault()

Answer (score 0):

```
q.Response = Answers.Any(a => a.QuestionID == question.ID) ? Answers.Where(a => a.QuestionID == question.ID).FirstOrDefault().Response;
```

Comment: syntax error ':' expected

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use C# 6.0, I would suggest to try new [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

```
q.Response = Answers.Where(a => a.QuestionID == question.ID).SingleOrDefault()?.Response;
```

It returns `null` when  `Answers.Where(a => a.QuestionID == question.ID).SingleOrDefault()` returns default value, which is null.

If you need something else, not `null`, you can use [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

```
q.Response = Answers.Where(a => a.QuestionID == question.ID).SingleOrDefault()?.Response ?? response, what you need;
```